# Derive Entity class from a NotMapped class in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to derive two of my Entity classes from a base class that does not belong to the model.

```
[NotMapped]
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    [NotMapped]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
public partial class Derived1: BaseClass {}
public partial class Derived2: BaseClass {}
```

I have tried marking the base class and all its properties as `[NotMapped]` but the context initializer throw an error saying that both my derived entity classes are not mapped.

Comment: Any chance you can use an interface instead?

Comment: No. It's the code that needs to be centralized rather than the contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. The [NotMapped] attribute should not have been applied to the base class, but only its properties.