# NotMapped on class instead of member

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have came across this question:

[Derive Entity class from a NotMapped class in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511108/derive-entity-class-from-a-notmapped-class-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first)

but since I am doing it codefirst, what is the best way of creating a POCO class that is not to be generated as tables in database, but just a helper class to hold other models together?

Edited: Example of the helper/helping class

```
[NotMapped]
public class Dashboard
{
     private VehicleDbContext db = new VehicleDbContext(); //Where DbSet of models are declared
     public List<User> UserList{get; set;}
     public List<Car> CarList{get;set;}

     public Dashboard()
     {
         Initialize()
     }
     private void Initialize()
     {
         CarList = db.Cars.ToList();
         UserList = db.Users.ToList()
         //more init algo
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just mean that you want to `Ignore` certain type, try this in your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Ignore<Dashboard>();
}
```

Still, you're saying

> but just a helper class to hold other models together

It's not quite clear what you mean by 'hold other models together', it could be that you must persist this type into the database to make it work.

Comment: For example, I have models `User, Car, License`. Supposed that I want to create some sort of dashboard that contains information from these models. I read somewhere that the best practice is to create a class i.e. `Dashboard` and from there, create the controller and views. So, I followed this suggestion but since codefirst method will create tables out of class, I need a way to tell that this class should not be generated. Any idea?

Comment: Does your `User/Car/License` entities contain a reference to `Dashboard`?

Comment: No. But those models are related to each other.

Comment: Is your `Dashboard` class defined in the same assembly as your `DbContext`?